# Magento 2 : How to remove & adjust some value from wishlist?

Tags: magento2

**Remove:** I want to remove the quantity text field & I don't want to use CSS to hide qty text field.

**Adjust:** I want to show Edit & remove the link above the add to cart button. How to do this by move & destination syntax?

**Updated 1:** Need to move to delete icon above add to cart button **(DONE).**

**Updated 2:** How to remove quantity text field. (**Done**)

[image]

Comment: can you please explain your question using screenshot? it would be much better to  understand

Comment: @WaqarAli, I have Upadted my question

Comment: Have you removed the quantity text field?

Comment: Yes, it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme please create the below files and add the code.

> app/design/frontend/[Theme_Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Wishlist/templates/item/column/cart.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart $block */

/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $item */
$item = $block->getItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();
?>
<?php foreach ($block->getChildNames() as $childName): ?>
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getLayout()->renderElement($childName, false) ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
    <?php if ($item->canHaveQty() && $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <div class="control">
                <input type="hidden" data-role="qty" id="qty[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($item->getId()) ?>]" class="input-text qty" data-validate="{'required-number':true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
               name="qty[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($item->getId()) ?>]" value="<?= /* @noEscape */ (int)($block->getAddToCartQty($item) * 1) ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="product-item-actions">
        <div class="actions-primary">
            <button type="button" data-role="tocart" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getItemAddToCartParams($item) ?>' title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>" data-item-id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($item->getId()) ?>" class="action tocart primary">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if ($product->getIsSalable()): ?>
            <p class="available stock" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Availability')) ?>">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span>
            </p>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p class="unavailable stock" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Availability')) ?>">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span>
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

> app/design/frontend/[Theme_Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Wishlist/layout/wishlist_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="customer.wishlist.item.actions" destination="customer.wishlist.item.inner" before="customer.wishlist.item.cart"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

And **flush the cache**, Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Please accept an answer if it will work for you, So it also helps others.

Comment: thanks, Kishor but after doing this  <move element="customer.wishlist.item.remove" destination="customer.wishlist.item.inner" before="customer.wishlist.item.cart"/>  it has moved remove icon above add to cart. Thanks for your answer, I have accepted this.

Comment: Can you please help me in second part of question, how to remove quantity text fields

Comment: Don't move the ""customer.wishlist.item.remove", I have suggested "customer.wishlist.item.actions".

Comment: You have this file in your theme "Magento_Wishlist/templates/item/column/cart.phtml" ?

Comment: I have done the same but the icon hadn't moved above add to cart so I have change element. ok I will try once again with "customer.wishlist.item.actions"

Comment: Yes in my custom theme copied from blank : "Magento_Wishlist/templates/item/column/cart.phtml"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104349/discussion-between-kishor-thummar-and-abhishek).